# Sticky navigation bar is not working

Tags: html, css, navigation, sticky

I'm trying to create a sticky navigation for `http://www.appledevice.expert`, and am having quite the difficult time.

I tried sticking the header with these attributes:-

```
position: fixed ;
width: 100% ;
```

It didn't work and threw all my content up under the header. I then tried to wrap the navigation bar in a new `div` class to anchor it and that didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us some code so we can help you out. Also, check out the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article and modify your question to align with those guidelines.

Comment: Can you share the code (html/css) you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Edit and give your header some attributes (commented new lines):

```
#header {
    line-height: 98px;
    background: #FFF url("images/header-top.png") repeat-x top center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d5d7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
    position: fixed; /*This is different*/
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%; /*This is new*/
}
```

Then add a top margin to your upper-most div after that to be equal the height of your header:

```
.sections:first-of-type {
      margin-top: 110px;
}
```

Comment: Added those attributes to the #header than applied the height function to <div id="wrap" class="stripe_grid_1200"> as suggested but did not fix the issue. 

Thank you for trying

Comment: Here's the header CSS:

line-height: 98px;
background: url("images/header-top.png") repeat-x scroll center top #FFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D5D7;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #E2E3E4;
position: relative; //**Tried changing this to fixed
z-index: 99999;
margin-bottom: 30px;
width: 100%; //*Tried changing this

I tried adding a height to every top section including:
.header
.sections
.container

None of those worked but at one point I did get the nav to stick with a top margin space, however the text for the top nav wasn't with the nav bar.

#super big headache on this

Comment: @No.1Deisgns It seems you're adding a lot of extra stuff.  When I went to your site, all I had to do is **exactly** what is in my answer above and it worked.  I'm not sure why you're adding a height function or adding height to every top section.  Just add `.sections:first-of-type { margin-top:110px; }` add `width:100%` and change `position:fixed` to #header only.

Comment: ....Where is .sections:first-of-type as I can not seem to locate this? Thanks in advance bud

Comment: .... After some research is see it's a pseudo element. Never herd of these before. Where do I add .sections:first-of-type. When I insert it into the upper most div it has a line through it, or is it inline?

Comment: @No.1Deisgns Do you have a CSS file set up? - Just copy and paste those lines into it.

Comment: I tried that, as well. 

.sections:first-of-type { 
margin-top:110px; 
}
.sections-left-sidebar .sidebar {
 float: left;
}
.sections-left-sidebar .main-content {
 float: right;

As you can see it's pasted. I also changed the other two elements. Still the same issue, bud.

Comment: @No.1Deisgns, I don't know what to tell you then.  I did exactly what I noted to your site within the element inspector in Chrome and it works just fine. possibly if you posted your relevant HTML that you need edited and CSS that goes with it, we might see something different.

Comment: Okay, lets try this from scratch lol.

Here is my #header CSS... for the url: www.appledevice.expert/blogs/apple-watch/apple-watch-prerelease.html

#header {
 line-height: 98px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d5d7;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
 z-index: 99999;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
#header > .container {
 position: relative;

I have tried inserting the .sections:first-of-type w/ margin of 110px
I am unable to make this work. I have no idea what other info I can provide

Comment: I downloaded chrome and when I try and add .sections:first-of-type w/ the height it just dissapears or turns red. Where are you entering this? I'm so confused and trying really hard

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue of the body moving under the header I applied this div code inside of the body;

div style="height:110px"

The body then moved down by the hight of the div element and left room for the top navigation bar.